# Passing Integer to @EnableJdbcHttpSession from properties file

Tags: spring-session

How to pass an Integer parameter from `application.yml` file into `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` annotation attributes?
It works like so:

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(tableName = "${some.string.property}")
```

But shows unexpected type if written like so:

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = "${some.Integer.property}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder resolution is supported only for `tableName` attribute of `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` (see [related `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration` code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L175-L190)).

But since you're mentioning `application.yml`, if you're using Spring Boot you can simply omit `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` and have Spring Boot auto-configure Spring Session for you. At that point, you can easily customize Spring Session JDBC using the following properties:

```
spring.session.jdbc.cleanup-cron=0 * * * * * # Cron expression for expired session cleanup job.
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=embedded # Database schema initialization mode.
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql # Path to the SQL file to use to initialize the database schema.
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION # Name of the database table used to store sessions.
```

See Spring Boot's [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-session) for more details.

Comment: I think I misguided you, sorry. In my project I have two portals and use two tables (both of which are inside one DB) for spring-session and have two configuration classes each of which has it's own table name in `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` annotation. So I cannot really omit that annotation.

Comment: It's not a problem - the first part of the answer (placeholder resolution is only used for `tableName`) still holds true. Can you open an [issue on Spring Session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues) and try to explain your use case in as much details as possible and we'll see if we can do anything reasonable about it?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Spring Boot then instead of @EnableJdbcHttpSession, you can add in application.properties below property
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.timeout =